# "Conic " sections on hyperboloid

Tags: conic-sections

What are eccentricities of "Conic" section created by intersection of a one sheet hyperboloid ( meridian $e >1 $) with a plane at inclination $\phi?$

Which inclination results in a hyperbola? a parabola? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid#Plane_sections

Comment: Thank you. The above Wiki has answers I wanted at one place... almost matching with expectation and intuition. Please answer if possible including how circular sections may be possible on a 1- sheet  hyperboloid; to me it ( barring the central obvious case) looked like counter-intuitive.

Comment: Start with a horizontal plane and rotate it about the major axis of the elliptic intersection: for some angle the minor axis will have the same length as the major one, thus giving a circle.

Comment: See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_section#Elliptical_hyperboloid_of_one_sheet

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answers but I think you can find them in the book *New Horizons in Geometry* by Tom M. Apostol and Mamikon A. Mnatsakanian, 2012.

or here

New Descriptions of Conics via Twisted Cylinders, Focal Disks, and Directors
(same authors as above)
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2008.11920594

Comment: Thanks, a very interesting reference, shall take a look.

Comment: you are welcome